# Digital rights problem

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, itunes

I have a movie I copied from my DVD into iTunes on my mac server. I can open TV app on my iPhone and it plays fine. When I try to play it on Apple TV using the Computers/server/Movies, it says there is a digital rights issue. 
How do I instruct Apple TV to accept the movie?

Comment: You could rip it using handbrake or whatever software people use nowadays.

Comment: I don't know for  you  but I personally use Plex Media Server and I'd totally recommend it. There's no native apple TV app, but I always just stream through my phone or tablet to the Apple TV doesn't really make a difference. Plex has great android and ios apps and a Web interface for desktop PCs. You can run the server on many different OS's.

Comment: Even in Plex I get the same message.

Comment: @William I could rip it, but don't understand why it works on iPhone but not Apple TV

Comment: What Apple TV model do you have and what version of tvOS is installed on it? Also, have you tested this behaviour with another DVD? Finally, what format was the copy you made of the DVD?